# Where is WolframLanguageSession in Google Colab?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, google-colaboratory

Looking into the **Wolfram Client Library for Python**, using the install approach from the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/):

```
pip install wolframclient

from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr
session = WolframLanguageSession()
```

This gives the **error**:

```
WolframKernelException: Cannot locate a kernel automatically. Please provide an explicit kernel path.
```

Obviously the default path depends on the environment and may also depend on the version. I looked into solutions [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/docpages/basic_usages.html#local-session-initialization) for specifying an explicit path, but not sure how to find this path on Google Colab.

Comment: Did you install a kernel?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the wolfram engine on colab, google would have to deploy it which is (in september 2020) not the case.

What you want to do is impossible on colab but works very well on a local instance of jupyter, by installing yourself the engine and following the procedure mentioned here : https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

Answer (score 0):

[Herein](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConnectPythonToTheWolframCloud.html) lies the answer.

Since a short answer is not accepted:

sign in to wolframcloud.com and get the key from there.

Then on colab:

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframCloudSession, SecuredAuthenticationKey
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr, wl
key = SecuredAuthenticationKey(
'3274928379750=',
'987345h87598375=')
session = WolframCloudSession(credentials=key)
session.start()
session.authorized()
session.evaluate('1+1')

## this was fun
a = session.evaluate(wlexpr("RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1,2], 100]"))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(a)
```

Have fun :)